Install GeoGebra 6 in Ubuntu 22.04
GeoGebra silently dropped Linux installation support between versions 5 and 6. How to install GeoGebra 6 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Yet you can have it. Follow the answer by francomariani88 dated June 29, 2023. (A) First you will install flatpak utility for software deployment, following this succinct two-minute video. [[ Probably redundant: (2) Download GeoGebra 6. (3) cd to where_you_downloaded/GeoGebra-Linux64-Portable-6-0-804-0/GeoGebra-linux-x64. ]] (B) In terminal run
flatpak install flathub org.geogebra.GeoGebra

Finally go to Show Applications and click GeoGebra to start (launch) the application.
